# Bluetooth communication between Raspberry Pi 4 and Arduino BLE 33 failure

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect with this code in my Arduino BLE 33:

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

String temperature;

BLEService ledService("19B10010-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); // create service

// create switch characteristic and allow remote device to read and write
BLEByteCharacteristic ledCharacteristic("19B10011-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);
// create button characteristic and allow remote device to get notifications
BLEByteCharacteristic buttonCharacteristic("19B10012-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  // begin initialization
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");

    while (1);
  }

  BLE.setLocalName("Nano33BLE");
  // Start up the service itself.
  BLE.addService(ledService);
  BLE.setConnectable(true);
  BLE.advertise();

  Serial.println("Bluetooth device active, waiting for connections...");

  if (BLE.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("BLE connected!");
      while (1);
    }
}

void loop() {
  // poll for BLE events
  BLE.poll();

  temperature = "hibluetooth";  
  

  Serial.print(temperature);       //Muestra la temperatura en el puerto serie (Bluetooth)
  Serial.println(" °F");
  delay(2000);                   //El DHT22 manda datos cada dos segundos. Si se usa un DHT11, cambiarlo por delay(1000)

}
```

I'm pretty sure that my code works on Arduino but don't allow me to connect with Raspberry Pi 4 or my phone.
I use the Bluetooth option from the Raspberry Pi desktop, but tell me that it needs a confirmation from the device and then the time is over. Then I tried to use this command: `sudo bluetoothctl` following this [tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/dhorton668/bluetooth-weather-station-40d1e4), but I think is not successful the connection.

Also if someone has a Python code to receive data from Arduino using Bluetooth would be awesome. I have this one that I copy from this [post](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-perform-read-and-write-between-raspberry-pi-4-and-arduino-nano-ble/628029) and also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498289/how-to-perform-read-and-write-between-raspberry-pi-4-and-arduino-nano-ble-via-bl).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You set up the arduino as a BLE peripheral with the LED characteristic, right? The problem might simply be that you are trying to connect to the arduino using the system settings of your Phone/Raspberry. Bluetooth Low Energy devices usually do not appear on there. Try finding your arduino using a BLE scanner app such as 'nRF Connect`

Comment: I would question your "I'm pretty sure that my code works on Arduino" assumption as you haven't used `addCharacteristic` anywhere. Use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to verify you have the Bluetooth peripheral appearing correctly on the Arduino before moving on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you guys I test with [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile), apparently is connected but also says not bonded, and also is the firts time using nRF so I don´t know if is possible to see the String that  I'm trying to send.

Comment: With nRF connect you should be able to see all the services, characteristics, and descriptors of the device. nRF Connect also supports read, write, and notify of data on a characteristic (if the characteristic supports it).